# How do you create a new custom table tied to case type?

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, civicase, drupal-views

Drupal 7.39
CiviCRM 4.6.8
Webform Civi Integration version 7.x-4.11.

None of our case managers see any of the Civi back-end.  All of their interaction is through Drupal, Views and Webforms.  This enables us to set very specific permissions for what they can and can't see or do.

For the most part, it works great.  Thanks Coleman!

In the past, having user's select a case type to tie an activity to has resulted in bad data (choosing the wrong case type), we are trying to limit that by using webforms that add an activity to a specific case type.

The integration for CiviCase is not to the level of CiviEvent so it makes linking to specific webforms (that are tied to one case type) challenging on views that aren't of one case type.

The only way we've found to successfully link to the correct webform is to create views of one case type with a link to Add an Activity that opens the related webform.

We would like to tie urls to case types so that we could generate views for specific webforms in any view.

For example, we could create a view like this:
[image: Example Case/Webform Table]

I think that if I could create urls associated with specific case types, I could expose those fields to Views and have views of different case types that render the correct url to the specific webform.

Essentially, my idea was to add a table like this:
[image: Potential Teble]

I could join this table to the civicrm_case_type table in the views configuration and expose the appropriate fields.

Then in the view, I could rewrite that url to be node/1?[id] which would open the appropriate webfom with the appropriate client prefilled.

As you can see, I can add multiple urls to a case type.  So the links could be pretty flexible.

Am I nuts?
Is there an easier way to go about doing this that is already in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around for this issue.

For each case type description field, I entered the node id to the corresponding case activity Webform.  For example, for Case Type A there is a separate Add Activity Webform (node id 1).  So for the view I added the case type description field and rewrote it to Add New Activity and made it a link to http://example.com/node/[description]?cid2=[id1].